# css3 3d cube strange rotation behavior

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I have a css3 3d cube which I'm trying to get to rotate on a button click.  Right now it does rotate, but in a different way then I'd like.  I'm trying to have it so the cube position stays still, but rotates to the correct side.  Right now it rotates out of it's container div all of the time, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

You can see a demo of it not working quite right here: http://jsfiddle.net/bU33f/

HTML:

```
<h1>Cube 2 - show sides</h1>

<section class="container">
  <div id="cube" class="show-front">
    <figure class="front">1</figure>
    <figure class="back">2</figure>
    <figure class="right">3</figure>
    <figure class="left">4</figure>
    <figure class="top">5</figure>
    <figure class="bottom">6</figure>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="options">

  <p id="show-buttons">
    <button class="show-front">Show 1</button>
    <button class="show-back">Show 2</button>
    <button class="show-right">Show 3</button>
    <button class="show-left">Show 4</button>
    <button class="show-top">Show 5</button>
    <button class="show-bottom">Show 6</button>
  </p>

  <p>
    <button id="toggle-backface-visibility">Toggle Backface Visibility</button>
  </p>

</section>
```

CSS

.container {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto 40px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
         -moz-perspective: 1000px;
           -o-perspective: 1000px;
              perspective: 1000px;
    }

```
#cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
          transition: transform 1s;
}

#cube figure {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 196px;
  height: 196px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  line-height: 196px;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#cube.panels-backface-invisible figure {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
       -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#cube .front  { background: hsla(   0, 100%, 50%, 0.7 ); }
#cube .back   { background: hsla(  60, 100%, 50%, 0.7 ); }
#cube .right  { background: hsla( 120, 100%, 50%, 0.7 ); }
#cube .left   { background: hsla( 180, 100%, 50%, 0.7 ); }
#cube .top    { background: hsla( 240, 100%, 50%, 0.7 ); }
#cube .bottom { background: hsla( 300, 100%, 50%, 0.7 ); }

#cube .front  {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( 100px );
     -moz-transform: translateZ( 100px );
       -o-transform: translateZ( 100px );
          transform: translateZ( 100px );
}
#cube .back   {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX( -180deg ) translateZ( 100px );
     -moz-transform: rotateX( -180deg ) translateZ( 100px );
       -o-transform: rotateX( -180deg ) translateZ( 100px );
          transform: rotateX( -180deg ) translateZ( 100px );
}
#cube .right {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(   90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
     -moz-transform: rotateY(   90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
       -o-transform: rotateY(   90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
          transform: rotateY(   90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
}
#cube .left {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(  -90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
     -moz-transform: rotateY(  -90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
       -o-transform: rotateY(  -90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
          transform: rotateY(  -90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
}
#cube .top {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(   90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
     -moz-transform: rotateX(   90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
       -o-transform: rotateX(   90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
          transform: rotateX(   90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
}
#cube .bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(  -90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
     -moz-transform: rotateX(  -90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
       -o-transform: rotateX(  -90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
          transform: rotateX(  -90deg ) translateZ( 100px );
}

#cube.show-front {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( -100px );
     -moz-transform: translateZ( -100px );
       -o-transform: translateZ( -100px );
          transform: translateZ( -100px );
}
#cube.show-back {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateX( -180deg );
     -moz-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateX( -180deg );
       -o-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateX( -180deg );
          transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateX( -180deg );
}
#cube.show-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY(  -90deg );
     -moz-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY(  -90deg );
       -o-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY(  -90deg );
          transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY(  -90deg );
}
#cube.show-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY(   90deg );
     -moz-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY(   90deg );
       -o-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY(   90deg );
          transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY(   90deg );
}
#cube.show-top {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateX(  -90deg );
     -moz-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateX(  -90deg );
       -o-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateX(  -90deg );
          transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateX(  -90deg );
}
#cube.show-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateX(   90deg );
     -moz-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateX(   90deg );
       -o-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateX(   90deg );
          transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateX(   90deg );
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("button").click(function() {
        var currentSide = $(this).attr("class");

        $("#cube").removeClass().addClass(currentSide);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not good at js but I think you problem in cub center. you rotate your cube under one of it's vertexes.(I think I'm capt:)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from margin applied to figure by default.

Just set

```
#cube figure {
     margin: 0px;
     display: block;
     ...
```

Solves your problem

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/bU33f/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to fix your problem:

`-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;`

on each of the transition classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/bU33f/1/

Adding the same for other browsers should set you on your way :-) .